# CiviMail opt out language

Tags: civimail

I have the latest version 5.1.1 of civicrm.
A problem that kind of slipped past our organization in the past is that the page for opting out has been always in English.  Mostly people opted out still without a problem, because I guess most Slovaks know enough English to handle that sort of thing, but there would be occasional emails from people asking to unsubscribe that my boss/wife would get complaining about the opt-out process.

I though I had fixed it through setting CiviCRM to follow the Drupal language, which defaulted to Slovak unless I was logged in. Now I realize that just fixed everything but the text of the opt-out page.  So I've just changed default language of civicrm to be only Slovak and never change, and for good measure, set Drupal to just be in Slovak. (I can handle it after 8 years of living in Slovakia and learning the language!).

But still, my testing shows me the page for opt out is always in English:
[image]

The link for optout sent was:
https://info.cbreurope.sk/sk/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=somenumber&qid=somenumber&h=somenumber

What am I missing?  BTW, we are using the Mosaico plug in for sending emails. Could that be a problem?  Drush is running the cron jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Slovak translation of CiviCRM is only [16% complete](https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/) - so it's not surprising that some pages wouldn't be translated.  This template (`templates/CRM/Mailing/Form/Optout.tpl`) is correctly configured to be translated, so it seems that this is simply a case of untranslated strings.

If you or someone you know would like to improve the state of the Slovak translation, consider registering for a [Transifex account](https://www.transifex.com/signup/?join_project=civicrm).  You'll have the opportunity to enter translations for various English text, which will automatically be added to the Slovak translation files, which you can then download to your site.  You'll also be helping other Slovak-speaking organizations with your efforts!

Comment: Great. I've signed up for that, and will ask my wife to translate at least those things that we need that haven't been translated and put it there!